# `Series` acts on variables outside its argument?

Tags: series-expansion

I am trying to work with Taylor series. What I am trying to do is to express
$$
f(h) - f'(0) = f(h) - f'(h - h)
$$
such that only derivatives of $f$ with the argument $h$ appear, for example
$$
f(h) - f'(0) = f(h) - f'(h) + hf''(h) + \mathcal O(h^2)
$$

I tried to do is this way:

```
f[h] - Series[f'[s - h], {h, 0, 2}] /. s -> h
```

Strangely, this gives me
$$
\bigl(f(0) - f'(h)\bigr) - \bigl(f'(0) - f''(h)\bigr)h +\left(\frac{f''(0)}2 - \frac{f^{(3)}(h)}2\right)h^2 + \mathcal O(h^2)
$$
which is not what I wanted. How can this behaviour be explained?

---

For the record, the correct answer can be obtained by

```
f[t] - Series[f'[s - h], {h, 0, 2}] /. {t -> h, s -> h}
```

Comment: I really don't understand your question.  Are you just trying to compute $f(h)_\text{exact} - f(h)_\text{taylor}$?  In that case you should be using `f[h] - Series[f[h + δ], {δ, 0, 2}]`

Comment: I fixed some typos and explained what I want to get. Although the calculation itself may not be useful, I am asking for an explanation of the seemingly strange behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, but if you look in the docs under [`SeriesData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesData.html), it says

> When you apply certain mathematical operations to `SeriesData` objects, new `SeriesData` objects truncated to the appropriate order are produced.

That explains this interesting series of events:

```
Series[f[s + h], {h, 0, 2}]
g[h] - %
Series[g[h] - f[s + h], {h, 0, 2}]
Normal@% - Normal@%% // Expand
```

[image]

When I added `g[h]` to `-Series[f[s + h], {h, 0, 2}]` the system first converted `g[h]` to a `SeriesData` object with the same order and parameter.

You can do

```
f[h] - Normal@Series[f[s + h], {h, 0, 2}]
(* f[h] - f[s] - h Derivative[1][f][s] - 1/2 h^2 (f^′′)[s] *)
```

But that isn't really what you are looking for, since you still want the [Big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).  Your method of working around this,

```
f[t] - Series[f'[s - h], {h, 0, 2}] /. {t -> h, s -> h}
```

(* (f(h)-f^′(h))+h f^′′(h)+1/2 h^2 (-f^(3)(h))+O(h^3)  *)

works in the following way.

1. First, `Series[f'[s - h], {h, 0, 2}]` is evaluated, giving a `SeriesData` object.
2. Next, before `f[t]` can be added to `-Series[f'[s - h], {h, 0, 2}]`, it is first converted to `Series[f[t], {h, 0, 2}]`
3. Now the two `SeriesData` objects are combined into one
4. The application of the replacement rule `t->h` occurs *inside* the `SeriesData` head, so there is not further application of `Series`

Comment: I don't really want to lose the Landau symbol. Are there any issues with using `t` instead of `h` and then replacing it `/.t->h` which may occur?

Comment: No problem at all, I was just trying to help understand why you have to take that circuitous route to get there  :-)